# Geany - change filetype for individual files

Tags: linux, editor, geany

I have a file with extension js.php which is mostly javascript. There's only small php at the top. I'd like to have this file viewed as javascript, not php and unfortunately geany doesn't seem to allow to manually change filetype just by selecting from the list, like most editors do. I tried adding *.js.php to filetype_extensions.conf but it doesn't work, it's still viewed as php. I like Geany and I'm using Linux, so using another text editor is probably not an option.

Comment: Selecting via Document->Filetype should work. If not, you might have found a bug and this would be off topic here.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow didn't notice this option.

Answer (score 2):

There is manual solution :  After Opening Geany and your file Choose following through the Menu bar

```
     Document
            -> Set FileType
                          -> Scripting Languages
                                              -> Javascript source file
```